# Clearing memory_get_peak_usage Cache

Tags: php, magento, xdebug

I'm trying to track down a memory leak in a PHP Program (Magento, if it matters).  The basic problem seems to be a leak in some object/class that's growing over time.  That is, the more information that gets logged to the database, the more memory certain application processes end up using.  Magento's a highly abstract system, so it's not always clear what code is being run that's consuming so much memory.  That's what I'm trying to track down.

I've been using `memory_get_peak_usage` at the end of the program bootstrap file to benchmark performance, and seen a steady growth from 250MB of peak use, to 310MB of peak use in about a week.  I would like to use `memory_get_peak_usage` intermittently throughout the execution cycle to ask

> What was the peak usage prior to this call?  [later in the cycle] What was the peak usage prior to this new call?

The problem I'm running into is, once I call `memory_get_peak_usage` once, any future call returns the same value as the first call, even when I know the peak usage has changed. This leads me to believe that after `memory_get_peak_usage` is called once, PHP caches the result.  I would like to uncache it to perform the testing outlined above.

1. Can I call `memory_get_peak_usage` multiple times?
2. Are there alternative to profiling the scenario I've described above.  Some feature of xDebug maybe?

Comment: Also take a good look at [xhprof](http://www.google.com/search?q=xhprof), which might give you a better overview of resource use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I call memory_get_peak_usage multiple times?

Not sure on that one.

> Are there alternative to profiling the scenario I've described above. Some feature of xDebug maybe?

Have a look at the [XDebug profile page](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). It's been awhile since I have profiled an app, but when I did I followed the write-up and worked great.

Comment: I take it you were able to profile the application, did you find out why the memory leak?